# Adding an object to a vector whilst looping through it

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop, vector

I have a vector of `GameObject*`in my "Level" class.

```
vector<GameObject*> gameObjects;
```

I add an object to Vector like this:

```
gameObjects.push_back(new Laser(10, 30));
```

where `Laser` is a child class of `GameObject`. I then loop through them like this:

```
void Level::update() 
{
    for(vector<GameObject*>::const_iterator i = gameObjects.begin(); i != gameObjects.end(); ++i) {
        (*i)->update();
    }
}
```

where `void update()` is a member function of class `GameObject`. Now at one point I may update an object, like a "gun", which creates another object, like a "bullet", in it's process, like this:

```
level.gameObjects.push_back(new Bullet(position, rotation));
```

Where `level` is an instance of the "Level" class. This line of code works just find, but at the end of that "frame", when the `level.update()` has finished looping through the existing `GameObject`s it crashes. This happens before it exits the for loop.

Why does it crash and how can I get round this issue?

Comment: [`push_back` can invalidate all the iterators in a `vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

Comment: `i` is invalidated once you `push_back`.

Comment: So how do I get around that?

Comment: You could avoid using iterators, and instead do `for (vector<GameObject*>::size_type i = 0; i < gameObjects.size(); ++i) gameObjects[i]->update();`

Comment: If you have to use iterators, have `update()` return the result of `level.gameObjects.insert(level.gameObjects.end(), new Bullet(position, rotation))` and assign that result to `i`. Otherwise go with Cornstalks' answer.

Comment: using indicies still crashed my game. I will try @0x499602D2 's

Comment: @Yaxlat You could iterate by index instead of iterator, you could make a copy of the vector to iterate over, you could use a different kind of container that is not invalidated by `push_back` like a list, if you are careful you could reserve enough space in the vector to be sure that allocation will not happen, you could delay adding the new objects to the vector until after `update` is complete.

Comment: @Yaxlat If using indices still caused a crash you are doing something else wrong. Are you erasing objects from the vector?

Comment: I solved the issue, thanks for your help! The crash with indices was caused by something else, now they work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding new items to a vector might require reallocation, if the new [size](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/) would exceed the [capacity](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/).  When this happens, the iterators are [invalidated](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/).

Potential solutions:

- iterate using the index for direct access to vector elements (easiest solution)
- make sure that enough capacity is [reserved](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) before you start using the iterator (not always possible).